# Which ASM style does g++ use

Tags: assembly, coding-style, g++, intel, att

I was wondering which ASM style g++ uses (AT&T or Intel). I'm working on an assignment that requires me to provide definitions for various ASM instructions. I saw the below:

```
movl    %esp, %ebp
where %esp = stack pointer and %ebp = base pointer
```

The [Intel style](http://sig9.com/articles/att-syntax) says the above equates to:

```
movl    destination, source
```

But it doesn't make sense to move the base pointer into the stack pointer, making me wonder if g++ uses the AT&T ASM style.

Here's the command I used to produce the ASM (and platform info):

```
g++ -S src -o out.bin
OS: Fedora Linux 14, 2.6.35.10-74.fc14.i686
Compiler: gcc version 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4) (GCC)
```

My Question: Is there anyway to definitively tell which style g++ is producing? Is there some switch.

**Please correct me where I am wrong. Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

G++ targets the GNU assembler `gas`, which uses AT&T syntax (*op*  *src*  *dest*) unless you use the [`.intel_syntax` directive](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dSyntax.html#i386_002dSyntax).

Comment: Hi! Thanks a million for the reply. I looked at the man page for GNU as (man as) and didn't see any reference to the ASM syntax used. Would you happen to have a link I could follow. My professor is a stickler for accuracy and I'd like to have an official document that supports my work. Thanks again!

Comment: @certifiedNoob: I added an authorative link to the GNU as manual (at sourceware.org, linked from gcc.gnu.org).

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that you can cause gcc itself to emit Intel syntax code by providing the `-masm=intel` commandline argument.

Answer (score 2):

It most certainly produces AT&T syntax, and what you are seeing is correct.  Notice that the stack pointer is moved into the base pointer after the base pointer is itself preserved on the stack.  This is standard stack frame boilerplate emitted by gcc on x86.

Also note that before your `ret`, the stack frame is restored via `leave`, which is equivalent to

```
movl %ebp,%esp
popl %ebp
```

Comment: you're correct, the very first line is a "pushl %ebp" followed by the code I listed originally. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: +1 for exactly the answer to my own question.  Thanks.  I'm trying to follow the logic of assembly code for the first time.  I used g++ to produce the output of a very simple program and 'leave' was bothering me.